# µTorrent and Windows 7 RTM x64

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, utorrent

I have read some places that µTorrent doesn't cooperate well with Windows 7 x64. What I have read was about the beta and RC versions though.

Does anyone have any experiences using it in the RTM version?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

Comment: Cool. Will accept this as answer since you have the least rep, and you took the time of taking a screen shot :p

Comment: There is no proof that is Windows 7 about page, it could be Vista :)

Comment: @Diago: OK, I will post a new screenshot.

Comment: @TFM - I was having some fun with this one but thanks :)

Comment: I know, but it was not a big deal to get a new screenshot, I owe it to Svish after the nice gesture.

Comment: @TFM: still not sure if this is the RTM or the RC version of windows 7 (tongue in cheek ;-)

Comment: hehe, be niice :P

Comment: I like your 2.0 experience index.

Comment: @Mark: My 2.0 experience index is because of my graphics card, it sucks. Earlier, I posted an image that didn't show my index, but Diago didn't like it. :p

Answer (score 6):

uTorrent works perfectly in Windows 7 RTM.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about the RTM, but I have been using it on Windows 7 x64 RC for several months without any problems at all.  I would expect the same, or better, behavior from RTM.

Comment: Me too. x64 rc7100.

Answer (score 3):

utorrent works well in windows 7. i have a copy from msdnaa and i use utorrent daily with no problem

Answer (score 2):

I'm running it on x64 RTM with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

The only real problem is likely if you set the downloads folder to be some folder under 'Program Files (x86)', I think it defaults to your vista/7 'Downloads' folder now, but for a while it did default to a subfolder of the installation path.

As with any program under vista/7, write access to 'Program Files'/'Program Files (x86)' is severely curtailed, even when granted administrative rights via UAC.

It's possible this would be a source of problems for people with 7 in the past, especially if they did an inplace upgrade from XP where the program files folder would be the location for downloaded torrents.